# Is there any advantages of using Defraggler over Windows 10 defrag?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I wonder if the performances are the same or not.
I have a program which generates a lot of fragmentation and I need to defragment these files after.

Comment: Defraggler lets you defrag a single file, which windows baked in tool doesn't AFAIK. In terms of performance difference, there's likely some documentation in the piriform website about that.

Comment: Varies depending on version of windows.......https://forum.piriform.com/topic/26926-defraggler-vs-windows-defrag/